How to determine Viscous Friction Damping Coefficient?
I was studying The Simscape Stirling Engine Model and in the Slider Crank - Flywheel part in the rotational damper block, it requires the value of damping coefficient in the script it uses this equation:
$$
\text{Crank Wheel Rotational damper} = \log(4) \dfrac{R_\text{crank wheel}}{\tau} 
$$
where $\tau$ is something called time for inertia speed to drop down to 25% of the original speed.
Can someone help me understand where did it get this equation from? I looked through my reference and didn't find anything.
